# How to build a source histogram (Anylogic)?

Tags: anylogic

I´m new with Anylogic.

My Question is: How can I build a histogram of a Source-Distribution?

(I want to visualize my set arrival-specifications)

Comment: welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. It is important here to show what research you already did to answer the question (helps us avoid replying things you already know). Please always do your homework first :-) Also check SoF guidelines for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Histogram Data object and link it to a Histogram.
Then, in the "on exit" code box of your source object, add `myHistogramData.add(time());` which will add the current time (when the source created an agent).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I checked out the way as described above. The problem is that in this way, I get kind of a timeline showing the separate point of times when the source created an agent – but I want to create the distribution function.  Therefore I think I need to add the interarrival times, and not the current time when the source created an agent. Do you know how to get the interarrival times into the histogram data?

Comment: add a variable and use that to log the time of the previous arrival (0 initally). When a new arrival comes, amend the code to write "time()-myVairable" to the histogram object!

Comment: Okay, i got it. Thanks a lot.